# JDBC getString() from the column of foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I use mysql and jdbc to get table2Id.column in table1.
table2Id is a foreign key of table1.
And i use rs.getString("table2Id.column") get the error.

```
dbc = new DBconnection();
conn = dbc.getConnection();
PreparedStatement pst = "SELECT * FROM `table1`";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
String value = rs.getString("table2Id.column")
```

How can I get the column of foreign key?

Comment: What error do you get? Can you please post the exact error message? First guess: Remove the accents around `table1`. Oh, you don't have the alias `table2Id.column`, so try to do `rs.getString(1)` or the column number of that column when you receive all by `SELECT *`.

Comment: column not found. I think it's a wrong way to get the column of the table2.

Comment: If you want to select from table2, then you need to explicitly join to it in the `from`-clause.

Comment: thanks, this is a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting unknown column error, try with,

```
String value = rs.getString("table2Id");
```

And Change ``` PreparedStatement pst = "SELECT * FROM `` table1 `` "; ``` to `PreparedStatement pst = "SELECT * FROM table1";`

Comment: what is the different between both of them?

Comment: Remove the accents  \`. If we put \` it will take as a code format.

Answer (score 1):

You can not simply get table2 column with out specifying it in the query.

You need to add your column to query.

```
SELECT t1.column as column1, t2.column as column2,... from table1 t1, table2 t2 where etc..
```

Thereafter in your java code, you can access using aliases,

```
resultSet.getString("column1")
resultSet.getString("column2")
```

or using column position(Position start from 1)

```
resultSet.getString(1);
resultSet.getString(2);
```

Comment: yeah, but the table1 have many column i want to get, i just don't want to write every column.